# replace string if he meet condition from a map of strings

Tags: python

I need to replace some strings in a list, only when they are belonging to a specific list of strings:
for example:
if the string is '1/1.5' I want to replace it by '1.25'
if the string is '0/0.5' I want to replace it by '0.25'

```
['1/1.5', '0/0.5', '1/1.5', '0.5', '1', ''0/0.5']
```

to

```
['1.25', '0.25', '1.25', '0.5', '1', ''0.25']
```

**EDIT**
This is the list of strings I want to replace them if the occurs:

```
'0/0.5' replace it by '0.25'
'0.5/1' replace it by '0.75'
'1/1.5' replace it by '1.25'
'1.5/2' replace it by '1.75'
'2/2.5' replace it by '2.25'
'2.5/3' replace it by '2.75'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample = ["1/1.5", "0/0.5", "1/1.5", "0.5", "1", "0/0.5"]

replacements = {
    "0/0.5": "0.25",
    "0.5/1": "0.75",
    "1/1.5": "1.25",
    "1.5/2": "1.75",
    "2/2.5": "2.25",
    "2.5/3": "2.75",
}
for index, item in enumerate(sample[:]):
    sample[index] = replacements.get(item, item)

print(sample)
```

### Output:

```
['1.25', '0.25', '1.25', '0.5', '1', '0.25']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['1/1.5', '0/0.5', '1/1.5', '0.5', '1', '0/0.5']
for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i]=='1/1.5':
    a[i]='1.25'
  if a[i]=='0/0.5':
    a[i]='0.25'

print(a)
```

output

```
['1.25', '0.25', '1.25', '0.5', '1', '0.25']
```

Answer (score 0):

split and average if '/' is in string

```
data = ['1/1.5', '0/0.5', '1/1.5', '0.5', '1', '0/0.5']

for j,x in enumerate(data):
    x1 = x.split('/')
    if(len(x1)>1):
        avg = 0
        for i in x1:
            avg+=float(i)
        avg/=len(x1)
        data[j] = str(avg)

print(data)
```